# would you please explain these?

Tags: grammar

> Although we are not all in physical pain or mental anguish all the time, we do exist primarily in a state of being ill at ease in the world, of being alienated, “made other.”

Hi. Would anyone possibly explain the followings kindly in elaborate?

> in a state of being ill at ease in the world

> “made other.”

Could you please EXPLAIN THEM READILY(FREELY), because I can not understand them yet.

Many thanks

Comment: It seems to be speaking about the human condition (perhaps pessimistically). Ill at ease in that our instincts are not evolved for the modern world. "Made other" as in feelings of alienation (or difference) from other humans.

Answer (score 2):

It is not darkly enigmatic, nor particularly profound, and a dictionary search of any confusing word(s) should make it clear to you. Trust yourself.

Part of the interpretation depends on what it's context, but it can stand alone.

> Although we are not all in physical pain or mental anguish all the time, we do exist primarily in a state of being ill at ease in the world, of being alienated, “made other.”

A paraphrase might be

> Although we are not always aware of our suffering, in reality, we no longer live in deep relationship with our surroundings, but live "apart from them".

If one was philosophizing on our alienation from Nature, it might mean

When we lived in an agrarian society (or perhaps even before that), we had a deep sense of our world, living with (and accepting) nature, including the harm nature can do as a part of the cycle to which we belonged. Our "flight or fight" responses (this is so common it's almost a cliché) were acted upon appropriately. In our industrial and technological advancement, we lost our deep relationship to nature and to suffering, and now find ourselves without a sense of belonging in our world, either the one of nature or the one of our creation.

If it is being used in a context of not being at one with out spiritual nature, one can interpret it in that light. In fact, one can interpret it in all manner of contexts.

Comment: I don't think it's a particularly simple question. Understanding that *ill at ease* is a phrase that should be looked up *in toto*, and that *other* is being used as a noun rather than an adjective here, requires non-trivial leaps of logic.

Comment: @phenry - instead of debating my interpretation, you should feel free to provide your own deeper answer. It may well help the OP more than mine.

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer, just with your suggestion that it would have been easy to answer the question by resorting to a dictionary.